# Can I reopen a jupyter notebook running on my server?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I need to run some code that takes a lot of time, so I did the following:

1. use ssh to connect to my server, use screen to start jupypter notebook server without web browser.
2. use the following to redirect localhost:portOnMyMachine to port 8888 on my server:

   myName@serverAddress -NL portOnMyMachine:localhost:8888 ubuntu@DNSofMyServer
3. Open my browser with localhost:portOnMyMachine

And I could edit notebooks on my browser. Every time I need to edit my notebook, I just need to repeat 2 and 3.

However, if I run some large program, I cannot see which line the kernel is working on when I log in again. There is no "*" symbol after the line number anymore. I guess it is still running something, because it will put a '*' after any new line I want to execute.

So I was wondering if anybody could tell me how to re-open a running notebook and have it in the status before I close it?

Comment: This is something we plan to improve, but for now, some state is lost when you close the tab. If it's practical, leave the SSH tunnel and the browser tab open while your notebook is running. We know that's not a great answer. ;-)

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks for answering and provide a solution!